# Check a column for a sequence of values using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, pattern-matching

I wish to look for a pattern in my grouped data frame. I am trying to identify when there's been a sequence of 3 consecutive rows which contain the value 1 in the signal column and then to set the alert column to TRUE once the 3rd row of the signal column contains 1.

I can do this when the number of lags I wish to check is small but if I wanted to expand this to look for 30 consecutive values then the ifelse becomes unmanageable.

```
df <- data.frame(Group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
                 Signal = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1))
```

Per group check for three consecutive rows in the Signal column containing 1

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(Alert = ifelse(Signal == 1 & lag(Signal) == 1 & lag(Signal, 2) == 1, "Yes", "No"))
```

Is there a more scalable approach for larger lag values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `consecutive_id()` to group by the current run of 1s and 0s in the Signal column, and use `row_number()` to see if you've had at least `n` 1s. (You can, of course, remove the `consecutive_id(Signal)` signal column after the calculation is done.)

```
library(dplyr)
threshold = 3
df |>
  group_by(Group, consecutive_id(Signal)) |>
  mutate(
    Alert = ifelse(Signal == 1 & row_number() >= threshold, 1, 0)
  ) |>
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 11 × 4
#    Group Signal `consecutive_id(Signal)` Alert
#    <chr>  <dbl>                    <int> <dbl>
#  1 A          1                        1     0
#  2 A          1                        1     0
#  3 A          1                        1     1
#  4 A          0                        2     0
#  5 B          0                        2     0
#  6 B          1                        3     0
#  7 B          0                        4     0
#  8 C          0                        4     0
#  9 C          1                        5     0
# 10 C          1                        5     0
# 11 C          1                        5     1
```

Comment: thanks so much for this answer, I've never heard of consecutive_id before, I'll be using this the whole time now.

Comment: It's fairly new in `dplyr`, but `data.table` has had `rleid` which does the same thing for as long as I can remember.